# ios how to monitor enter or exit on polygon or rectangle region using geofencing

Tags: ios, objective-c, polygon, rectangles, geofencing

I want to monitor user enter or exit event inside a polygon or rectangle region but ios allow only circle region. Please help if anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Well, as you said, built-in geofencing uses a circular region. So clearly the "polygon or rectangle region" is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As you know iOS geofencing works on a radius from a given point, but you can use a technic called "[Circle Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing)" to a get a number of circles from any polygon.

Take a look at this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193482/how-to-calculate-how-many-polygons-i-can-put-inside-a-polygon)